# Java Showing Unknown Source Error

Tags: java

I want input the number of bytes that has to be be read from a text file. Also i have to output the corresponding line number of the last read byte. May i Know How can I resolve this issue.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner ("What integer");      
static int br = sc.nextInt();
```

Its pointing error in the nextInt

Comment: You need to show what changes you've made, where your code is locate, etc. In other words, put more detail into your question. As an aside, your creating a Scanner based on the String "What integer", a String that has no integers in it. If you need the Scanner to read in a File, you should pass a File object into it, not a String.

Comment: The above link contains my code

Comment: No, please don't do that. Some of us have firewalls that don't allow ability to get to links, and besides you're asking volunteers to help you, and so you should make it easy for them to do so. Post your code in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove static from you code . because you are writing static in code block. Static are only allowed in class and  outside of any other code block.

Answer (score 0):

Only field variables can be static. Remove `static` or move `br`'s declaration outside whatever method this resides in.

Furthermore, only static invocations can be made outside of methods inside classes. Invoking `sc.nextInt()` should be done inside of a method.